# SQL finding the average of a group by generated column

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a sakila table set of film (contains film_id) and film_actor(contains actor_id, film_id).
id like to find all actors that played in more movies than the average.
ive tried using:

```
select actor_id, count(film_actor.film_id) as film_count
from film, film_actor
where film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
group by actor_id
having film_count > avg(film_count)
```

I'm getting a

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

and don't understand why I cant preform the average function.

without the *HAVING* command I manage to generate

|actor_id| film_count|
|--------|-----------|
|   1    |   19      |
|   2    |   25      |
and so on. so why cant I average the film_count column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should express the overall average using a formal subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT fa.actor_id, COUNT(fa.film_id) AS film_count
    FROM film f
    INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
    GROUP BY fa.actor_id
)

SELECT actor_id, film_count
FROM cte
WHERE film_count > (SELECT AVG(t.film_count) FROM cte t);
```